Analyzing matching value frequency from ";" separated values in one column on Excel
I have a few thousand lines of excel data from a query system report. One of the columns is for "issue discussed" for the query, in which the person categorizing the query can select any number of issues for that query.
These issues are then stored in one column in the report, separated by a ";". There could be anywhere between 1 - 10+ values selected for each query from a list of over 20 different values.

I want to be able to identify for each value, the other values recorded against and the frequency they are recorded.
The only thing I have been able to achieve so far is creating a matrix and using a COUNTIFS formula to count partial matches. The vertical and horizontal axis have all the different values, with the following formula replicated to count how many times to corresponding values appear along side each other.
COUNTIFS(B:B,"*"&E4&"*",B:B,"*"&F2&"*")

## B:B = "Issue discussed" range
## E4 = an issue value (e.g. apple)
## F2 = an different issue value (e.g. melons)

Then using colour scales to represent the most common occurrences.

I just feel there is a better/more efficient way to do this, that is not as formula heavy and allows for scalability and filtering (not included in my sample data are dates for the query, query handler, type of query etc.).
I also have a Power Query that represents the data split at each issue discussed value, such as:



Query ID
Issue




1
apples


1
pears


1
melons


2
oranges


2
apples


3
plums



The above Power Query table is how I currently get a general count of how many times a query is selected and feeds into a Pivot Table.
Any suggestions or ideas would be very appreciated.

Since you are already using Power Query, you can write a query to output the frequency of each pair using your first table as the data source.
I have no idea how the efficiency compares with your current method.
If you have Power BI, there are many ways to display this data.
Custom function to generate all pairs from a listName this query fnAllPairs
//create a list of all possible pairs from a list
//assumes no duplicate entries within the list
//NAME this query "fnAllPairs"

(li as list)=>

let
    entries = {0..List.Count(li)-1},
    pairs = 
        List.Accumulate(
            entries,
            {},
            (s,c)=> s &
                List.Generate(
                ()=>[p={li{c}} & {li{c+1}}, idx=c+1],
                each [idx]<List.Count(li),
                each [p={li{c}} & {li{[idx]+1}}, idx=[idx]+1],
                each List.Sort([p])))

in 
    pairs

Main Query
let

//Change next line to reflect data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table7"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Query ID", Int64.Type}, {"Issue discussed", type text}}),

//Add a column which has all the pairs of that row
    #"Added Pairs Lists" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Pairs", 
        each fnAllPairs(Text.Split([Issue discussed],";")), type {text}),

//Remove unneeded original columns and expand the pairs list to one row per pair
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Pairs Lists",{"Query ID", "Issue discussed"}),
    #"Expanded Pairs" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Pairs")[Pairs],

//Remove the entries where there were no pairs (only a single Issue discussed)
    #"Remove nulls" = List.RemoveNulls(#"Expanded Pairs"),

//Create a list of distinct pairs
    #"Unique Pairs" = List.Distinct(#"Remove nulls"),

//generate a count for each distinct pair
    #"Count Pairs" = List.Accumulate(
        #"Unique Pairs",
        {},
        (s,c)=> s & {{Text.Combine(c,";")} & {List.Count(List.Select(#"Remove nulls",each _ = c))}}),

//convert the list of pairs and associated counts back to a table
    #"To Records" = List.Transform(#"Count Pairs", each Record.FromList(_,{"Pair","Frequency"})),
    #"To Table" = Table.FromRecords(#"To Records",type table[Pair=text,Frequency=Int64.Type]),

//Sort so most frequent is first
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"To Table",{{"Frequency", Order.Descending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"


I'd suggest looking at Power BI for how to present the data. Here is a simple matrix visual, similar to what you show above, but there are many other possibilities.

